# get date from dynamically created text field by ng-repeat to controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating management items dynamically using `ngRepeat` to manage items in web form but I have small problem with `$scope.newValueItem` is undefined maybe because I create it dynamically just I want to ask how can I get value from dynamically created input text?

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" name="itemsManagementRrnForm">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6" data-ng-repeat="(formControllerKey,formControllerValue) in displayModel track by $index">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">{{formControllerKey}}</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">
                                <ul>
                                    <li data-ng-repeat="formControllerValue in formControllerValue track by $index" data-ng-hide="formControllerValue.deleted">
                                        <div id="showItem" data-ng-show="!displayModel[formControllerKey][$index].editingMode">
                                            <input class="" type="submit" value="Edit" data-ng-click="toggleEdit(formControllerKey,$index)">
                                            <input class="" type="submit" value="Delete" data-ng-click="deleteValue(formControllerKey,$index)">
                                            <label>{{formControllerValue.formControllerValueName}}</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="editItem" data-ng-show="displayModel[formControllerKey][$index].editingMode">
                                            <input class="" type="submit" value="update" data-ng-click="updateValue(formControllerKey,$index)">
                                            <input class="" type="submit" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel(formControllerKey,$index)">
                                            <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="formControllerValue.formControllerValueName" placeholder="add new here">
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="" type="submit" value="add" data-ng-click="addValue(formControllerKey,formControllerValue[$index].formControllerID,$index)">
                                <input type="text" size="30" data-ng-model="newValueItem" placeholder="add new here">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('athena');

    var ItemsManagementRrnFormController = function ($scope, $location, authService, userInfoService, itemsManagementRrnFormService) {

        var username = '';
        $scope.addValue = function (formControllerKey, parentId,index) {

            $scope.model = formValueModelTemplate();
            $scope.model.formControllerID = parentId;
            $scope.model.createdBy = username;
            $scope.model.CreatedOn = new Date();
            $scope.model.modifiedBy = username;
            $scope.model.modifiedOn = new Date();
            $scope.model.formControllerValueName = $scope.newValueItem;
            $scope.displayModel[formControllerKey].push($scope.model);
            itemsManagementRrnFormService.postValue($scope.model);
            $scope.newValueItem = '';

        };
    };

    app.controller('ItemsManagementRrnFormController', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService', 'userInfoService', 'itemsManagementRrnFormService', ItemsManagementRrnFormController]);

}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your running into a scoping issue.

Your controller has its own scope and there is only one `$scope.newValueItem` in it.

However `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each iteration, your controller's `$scope.newValueItem` is independent to each in the ng-repeat;

So your options are to either pass the `newValueItem` into the add method or in each display model expand it to have a value for the input. This will allow you to clear each one individually when you click add and also stops Angular duplicating `newValueItem` on each `ng-repeat` child scope.

```
$scope.displayModel = {
   controllerKey1: {
      data: [],
      newValueItem: ''
   }
}
```

I created a quick fiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/g9tm6y0c/5/

EDIT: Created an example fiddle demonstrating the scoping.
http://jsfiddle.net/9w0dy8ut/